# Why mysql_connect is not work in PHP version 7.2

Tags: php

One of my client project in PHP Old version (5.5) and used `mysql_connect()` and other function related on it so there are lot's of file has used PHP old version functions but now we want to migrate in new version `7.2` but old version's function of `mysql` is not working.

My question is not duplicate i have also referred in stack overflow but in my projects there are lot's of files that have been used old version function so how could i use same in new version.

Is there have any way to use same function in new PHP version ?

Comment: you can use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, but don't try to use `mysql_*` functions anymore! You need to use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: So you mean to say i need to change in all files , it's around 100

Comment: Yes. The amount of files doesn't care in this case. You can use `mysqli_*` because it is nearly the same syntax compared to `mysql_*`. You should also use prepared statements.

Answer (score -1):

Use their mysqli it will solve the problem..

```
mysqli_connect()
```